# Converting Dataframe to nested dictionary/tree in Python

Tags: python, tree

Right now I have a CSV file that looks like this:

[image: Current data in my csv file]

I need to convert this data to a nested dictionary, where there are different levels, depending on the levels (or columns) in my table. The result should look like this:

```
dictionary = {A:{C:1,D:{G:2,H:3},E:4},B:{C:{I:2,J:3},D:10}}
```

In other words, if there is a 'child' to the column, there needs to be another level of depth in the tree.

Is there any function in Python that can do this? Or do I need to write my own function?

Comment: You are right! I was looking for the right syntax, so I will edit the question! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

how to use groupby

```
my_dict = df.groupby('A')[['B','C','D']]
       .apply(lambda x: x.set_index('B').to_dict(orient='index'))
       .to_dict()

print (my_dict)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? I am not really sure what you are doing and it doesn't seem to work for my problem.